# React-Bootstrap Tabbed Interface with .map() function not keeping each tab unique on click

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap, array.prototype.map

I am using a React-Bootstrap Tabbed Interface to map an array of users, and then ideally when clicking on each tab you will see various information for that user.

I've correctly been able to map the data, and I get unique info for each user within the data, but every tab's active status is enabled for all tabs because every tab has the same **href** and **eventKey** inside of my map function and I am having trouble conceptually trying to understand and figure out how to map through the array and have each eventKey and href be different for each Tab on each iteration...

> TabbedInterface.tsx

```
<ListGroup>
        {data.map((item: any, i) => (
            <ListGroup.Item key={i} action href={"#Link"}>
                {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
            </ListGroup.Item>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={8}>
      <Tab.Content>
            {data.map((item: any, i) => (
                <Tab.Pane key={i} eventKey={"#Link"}>
                    {item.company_name} {item.id}
                </Tab.Pane>
            ))}
      </Tab.Content>
```

On every iteration, the href and eventKey stay as **"#Link"**, but I need each iteration to change the eventKey and href so that only one tabbed can be clicked at a time...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using an href={} in the ListGroup.Item component, I used the eventKey={} prop in both the ListGroup.Item and Tab.Content component and set the prop to eventKey={i} to keep them unique. The indicator was in the React-Bootstrap documentation it said: eventKey => Similar to React's key prop, in that it only needs to be unique amongst the Components siblings.

```
<ListGroup>
        {data.map((item: any, i) => (
            <ListGroup.Item key={i} action eventKey={i}>
                {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
            </ListGroup.Item>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={8}>
      <Tab.Content>
            {data.map((item: any, i) => (
                <Tab.Pane key={i} eventKey={i}>
                    {item.company_name} {item.id}
                </Tab.Pane>
            ))}
      </Tab.Content>
```